# How do I deserialize a different structured JSON data in Marshmallow?

Tags: python, json, deserialization, marshmallow

I have a `Schema` as below:

```
from marshmallow import Schema, fields

class ContactSchema(Schema):
    # ... other fields ...
    phone = fields.Str()
    # ... other fields ...
```

However, JSON data I deal with is different:

```
{
    // ... other data ...
    "information": {
        "address": "foo",
        "email": "bar@baz.com",
        "phone": "+101234567890"
    }
    // .. other data ..
}
```

As you can see, `phone` key is under `information`, which is different than how `ContactSchema` is formed.

Can I, and how can I, map a `Field` under a `Schema` to a different path in target JSON data?

---

#### Environment

- Python 3.5 and above
- Marshmallow 2.16.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend your schema and provide a `pre_load` method:

```
class ContactSchema(Schema):

    @preload
    def extract_information(self, data):
       # Please check for None's
       data['phone'] = data['information'].pop('phone')
       return data
```

Comment: Ah, yeah, it seems I couldn't understand the purpose of `preload` anyway. The solution was simple. Thanks. :)

Comment: You should read [the relevant documentation](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/2.x-line/extending.html). It has more use cases and examples